# Why isn't the width or margin in my @media query registering properly?

Tags: css

The query in question is the max-width of 400px at the bottom of the coding.

```
/*MAIN ELEMENTS*/

body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*width:1266px; height:612px;*/
    background-color:#161616;
    background-image:url(http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Pics/Background.png);
    /*background-position:top 40px center;*/
    background-position:50% 11px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    /*top:40px;*/
    z-index:1;
    }

header{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:4;
    }

footer{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:4;
    }



/*DECORATIVE ELEMENTS*/

#header_border{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    background-image:url(http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Pics/header.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#960;
    /*background-size:100%;*/
    }

#footer_border{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    background-image:url(http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Pics/footer.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#960;
    /*background-size:100%;*/
    }



.page{
    width:88%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .44);
    border-radius:22px;
    margin:88px auto;
    }

#row{
    width:77%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:11px auto;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    }

#row li{
    width:20%;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:16pt;
    border-radius:6.5px;
    margin:0 2% 0 2%;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    }




.sect_container{
    width:88%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:rgba(204, 204, 204, .55);
    border:solid 2px #666;
    border-radius:22px;
    margin:11px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    }

.sect_title{
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:22pt;
    margin:6px 0 0 6px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    }

.link{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    /*background-color:#F00;*/
    position:absolute;
    top:33%;
    }

/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media(max-width:400px){
        #header_border{background-image:url(Pics/Header_400w.png); height:12px;}
        #footer_border{background-image:url(Pics/Footer_400w.png); height:12px;}
        .sect_title{font-size:14pt; margin:auto; float:none;}
        #row{width:100%}
        #row li{font-size:10pt; height:30px; width:88%; margin:4% auto; clear:both; float:none;}
        }

@media(max-width:700px){
        #header_border{background-image:url(Pics/Header_400w.png); height:12px;}
        #footer_border{background-image:url(Pics/Footer_400w.png); height:12px;}
        .sect_title{font-size:16pt;}
        #row li{font-size:10pt; height:44px; width:44%; margin:4% 0 4% 4%;}
        }

@media(max-width:900px){
        #header_border{background-image:url(Pics/Header_900w.png);height:29px;}
        #footer_border{background-image:url(Pics/Footer_900w.png);height:29px;}
        .sect_title{font-size:18pt;}
        #row li{font-size:14pt; height:60px;}
        .link{top:11%;}
        }
```

When I reduce the screen size the `#row li` doesn't display at `88%` as I have it set to and the `.sect_title` doesn't margin to the middle.  The funny thing about it is when I comment out the second media query of `700px` wide the `#row li` go to `88`% wide, but they float all the way to the right.

Here's a fiddle of it in action https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/5be35wdm/2/
can someone please help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The media query `900px` has more priority so it overrides media query `700px` and `400px` so you have to change the order of your `media queries`. For centering `#row`, you should set `margin` and `padding` to `0`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5be35wdm/6/)

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq Do you want to center `.sect_title` in small screen?

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq Give `text-align: center;`  to `.sect_title`. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5be35wdm/7/)

Comment: thanks, but I had already figured that part out yesterday. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the fact that the *last* rule in the stylesheet will override the ones preceding it. Thus, you want to place the more specific rules *last*:

```
/* MEDIA QUERIES*/
 @media(max-width:900px) {
    //...
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
    //...
}
@media(max-width:400px) {
    //...
}
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5be35wdm/3/), although it kind of looks better the way it was before...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to position text to the middle of the div when width is 400px;

**CSS:**

```
text-align: center; // in @media 400px
```

Regarding the `li` add `!important` behind the `88% !important;`

Good luck

Comment: Using `!important` is highly discouraged unless you know how and when to use it. From the provided code there is not sufficient reason to use `!important`.

Comment: @hungerstar not cool to mark down. As though you are correct what I told him worked in his jFiddle so it is relevant to his project. It is up to him to decide if he wants to use it or not. rank 5000+ should not be marking down just because you feel like it.

Comment: Please explain to me how I'm the one who down voted you? As a side note, when suggesting an answer that is widely considered to be _bad practice_, shouldn't the answer point out the cons of using it? OP may not be aware of those cons. My comment provided a basic context to know that the answer is _bad practice_ and that there are more well suited answers out there, albeit they would have to look into the use of `!important` themselves and discover the pitfalls of using it.

Comment: I am not trying to start a fight with you @hungerstar it just looked like it was you. I was maybe assuming but I got down voted and you were the comment below. In any case I agree with what you have said and I don't have a problem with it, I just don't see why (if it wasn't you) was the answer down voted that is all. (NO BEEF!)